# Open file in read-write mode in Rust

Tags: file, rust

In Rust, how do I open a file for reading *and* writing? `File::open()` is read-only, and `File::create()` claims is write-only (and also creates files which isn't what I want).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[As of Rust 1.58](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/85766) (the next release as I write this) you can do this:

```rust
use std::fs::File;

let mut file = File::options()
    .read(true)
    .write(true)
    .open("foo.txt")?;
```

On older versions you can use the [`OpenOptions`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html) struct to open the file. It's the same as the above code but a bit more weirdly named.

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
    .read(true)
    .write(true)
    .open("foo.txt")?;
```

Comment: Yes, this is one of the uses of the [builder pattern](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/builder.md) in the standard library.

Comment: @Boiethios: I still find the use weirdish. I'd have expected the builder to build an `OpenOptions` object which is then passed to a `File::open_with` function. That `OpenOptions` has the `open` method feels... strange.

Comment: It's not strange, it cuts out needless extra steps. Files aren't the objects you build, they're something you normally open or create, which is why finalizing method is `.open()`, not `.build()`

Comment: @Sahsahae: Nobody is suggesting it should be `.build()`. It's strange because most people would expect `let mut file = File::open_with_options("foo.txt", OpenOptions::new().read(true).write(true));`. In fact, I just checked and that's actually how it is implemented internally.

Comment: You can always use [`libc::fopen`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.63/libc/fn.fopen.html) if `std` is too convenient.

Comment: In nightly you [can now](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65429) do `File::with_options().read(true).write(true).open("foo.txt")` which is a lot better. :-)